# Parsing meta tags efficiently with lxml?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, css-selectors, web-scraping, lxml

I'm parsing HTML pages with lxml. The pages have meta tags as follows:

```
<meta property="og:locality" content="Detroit" />
<meta property="og:country-name" content="USA" />
```

How can I use lxml to find the value of the `og:locality` meta tag on each page, efficiently?

I've currently got the following, which just manually matches up meta tags by property:

```
for meta in doc3.cssselect('meta'):
    prop = meta.get('property')
    if prop === 'og:locality':
        lat = meta.get('content')
```

But it doesn't feel very efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think lxml supports most CSS selectors, so you could use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs):

```
doc3.cssselect('meta[property="og:locality"]')[0].get('content')
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use this XPath selector: `//meta[@property='og:locality']/@content`

Comment: You miss the `@content` no ?  
`tree = fromstring(html_data)
tree.xpath("//meta[@property='og:locality']/@content")`

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use another pure Python library, [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) could be an option...

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<meta property="og:locality" content="Detroit" />
<meta property="og:country-name" content="USA" />
"""

soup = Soup(html)
```

To parse exactly what you're looking for you would just ask for:

```py
soup.find("meta", {"property": "og:locality"}).attrs['content']
```

Which would output:

> 'Detroit'